# MySQL - Querying against a non-indexable field

Tags: mysql

The webpage in question is https://www.christart.com/poetry/

I have a MySQL table with little over 7,000 records of poems entries. I'm getting requests from my users to be able to run queries against they body of the poems. But they are saved in a 'text' column.

I know how to write the SQL statement. That's easy enough. My concern is the load on the database. I always index columns that are queried or join on. But can't index a 'text' column.

There must be a way. How should I approach this?

Comment: With only 7000 rows you shouldn't really see any performance gain from indexing the values vs leaving them unindexed.

Comment: I had a friend at school called Chris Tart. He was a bit of a poet. Is this his website? Anyway, why can't you index a text field?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin to manage table. The 'index' link is greyed out for fields with 'text' data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [full text index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX poem_contents ON poems(body);
```

And then search using `match`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   poems
WHERE  MATCH(body) AGAINST ('some phrase' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that you can't index a text field. That being said, there's probably very little value in indexing a text field that's containing entire poems.

If your database only has 7,000 rows, you probably won't see a massive performance hit unless you scale much larger than it currently is. For a larger scale, a better solution would probably be to extract keywords from the body and search on those.

Comment: @Scotty: That'll largely depend on what hardware you're running and what your system load looks like, but a 7000 record table is honestly trivial. Most databases I've looked into don't start seeing performance issues until they start getting into 100s of thousands if not in the millions range.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must explore Apache Lucene or similar kind of project which provide full text search. Alternatively you can check mongodb instead of mysql. It got number of index types. There are also Solr/ElasticSearch which at back uses Lucene.

Poem body, I assume, it will be stored in varchar type. I dont know indexing possible on varchar or not & dont think it wise to indexing entire poem body.  Something like Lucene/Solr provides better option.

Please note, I am not related to any of the product mentioned above.